# Css modal box z index doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build simple modal and for some reason the `z-index` doesn't work. what is the problem here?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var aTag = document.querySelector('.img-box');

  aTag.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    document.body.classList.add('overlay');

    var img = document.createElement('img'),
        modalBox = document.getElementById('modal-box')

    img.src = this.href;

    modalBox.appendChild(img);

  })
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#modal-box {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#modal-box img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://placehold.it/400x200" class="img-box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</a>

<div id="modal-box"></div>
```

Alternate demo: http://codepen.io/phpnetanel/pen/qEjJbo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you add the `.overlay` class to the document body. The rest of the content is held in the document body and thus it stays on top. Create a new overlay div and add it to the body and apply the `.overlay` class to it.

Here's a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaXdKw

Comment: There is a way to add this to body tag without cause this effect?

Comment: Well all elements that are contained in the body will stay on top. You cannot put a container outside of the body.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the `.overlay` class to the body. This will not create an overlay above the content like you are expecting. You need to create another element.

[This](http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/zxzmoE) should do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change position to relative in place of absolute in the #modal-box and it will work

Comment: I have absolute position set cause i want to center the modal box.

Comment: yes just put it relative and then, add margin:0px auto

Comment: `z-index` works just fine with `position: absolute`... thats not whats wrong here